# Getting nullPointerException with contentprovideroperation

Tags: android

I'm trying for updating a contact photo in android through code. Using content Provider Operation I've tried to update the photo. Update query's added in code snippet. But nothing happens. My code snippet is below.

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && data != null)

    {

        Uri contactData = data.getData();

        String[] projection = new String[] { Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                Photo.PHOTO };

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            String dataid = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID));
            String first = String.valueOf(dataid);

            byte[] dataid1 = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(Photo.PHOTO));
            String first1 = String.valueOf(dataid1);
            System.out.println("fisttry");
            System.out.println(dataid);
            System.out.println(first);
            System.out.println(first1);
            System.out.println(dataid1);

            try {

                System.out.println("fisttry");
                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                ContentProviderOperation.Builder op = ContentProviderOperation
                        .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);

                op.withSelection(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?"
                                + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                                + "=?",
                        new String[] {
                                String.valueOf(dataid),
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE });
                op.withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                op.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO,
                        photo);

                ops.add(op.build());
                System.out.println(op);
                System.out.println(ops);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Update

            try {
                this.getContentResolver().applyBatch(
                        ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                System.out.println("secondtry");
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }



}
```

Stacktrace:

```
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r69-303A36303A365A/71 (has extras) }} to activity {com.ileaf.camerafun/com.ileaf.camerafun.TrialActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3521)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3563)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:126)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.applyBatch(ContentProviderNative.java:454)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:95)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:622)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at com.ileaf.camerafun.TrialActivity.onActivityResult(TrialActivity.java:513)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3517)
01-12 01:19:22.202: E/AndroidRuntime(16057):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Altogether now: "post the stacktrace".

Comment: Please show us like 513 of `TrialActivity`.

Comment: I recommend that you revise your code. You're doing a lot of ` applyBatch` calls, for all the entries in `Data.CONTENT_URI`.

Comment: Why do you keep "// TODO Auto-generated method stub" when you implemented a method?

Answer (score 0):

This is an activity lifecycle issue. When you invoke `startActivityForResult()`, the starting activity gets suspended and can, if Android gets short of resources, be destroyed altogether.

When you return from the activity you started, the call to `onActivityResult()` happens early in the activity lifecycle - so for example a call to 'getActivity()' inside `onActivityResult()` in a fragment will return null if the activity was actually destroyed, but return a non-null value if it wasn't destroyed.

Therefore you can't reliably do anything complex in the `onActivityResult()` method. I have two patterns I use here. The first is to just use `onActivityResult()` to store the response in instance variables and then take action in the `onResume()` method; the second is to conditionally execute code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (getActivity() != null) {
        // as we have an activity, it wasn't destroyed, and we can do stuff here
    }


}
```

Which solution you use depends on the scenario you are dealing with. I use the first solution when transient data is being returned through the data intent (as this is the only way I get it), and the second when the call to `onActivityResult()` is just a notification that I should refresh the view from data stored elsewhere.